# php addslashes becomes illegal token in javascript

Tags: php, jquery

i tried using jquery ajax call, everything works fine until i tried to escape the json string using addslashes on the the server side i get the follow error : unexpected token illegal. here is my json string i cant find any problems in it

```
[{\"shortlist\":{\"id\":\"46\",\"application_id\":\"3\",\"created\":\"2012-04-
22\",\"modified\":\"2012-04-22\"},\"application\": 
{\"id\":\"3\",\"admissionsession_id\":\"0\",\"school_id\":\"\",\"surname\":\"oni\",\"
other_names\":\"oluwafemi timothy Toluwalope\",\"date_of_birth\":\"0000-00-    
00\",\"created\":\"2012-04-15\",\"modified\":\"2012-04-15\"}}]
```

if i remove the addslahes from the php json string it works fine. am scared of leaving my string unescaped tho.

Comment: You're misusing escapes.  Use a real JSON library.

Comment: Why are you adding backslashes to the quotation marks that are part of JSON syntax?

Answer (score 1):

add your data structure in an array:

```
$data = array('shortlist' => array('id' => 46, ....
```

then use:

```
$json = json_encode($data);
echo $json;
```

Comment: what do you do with json in js?

Comment: @Gavriel: hats what i did, $data is a result of a query, but instead of just: echo $json am doing echo addslashes($json) because if there are single quotes in $json javascript will throw "; expected"

Comment: @El' : use eval to convert to javascript array

Comment: why no just use jQuery to do it? set dataType to 'json' and data will be your array. jQuery.get( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] [, dataType] ) http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: put here your code, 'cause you're doing something wrong. Obviously you shouldn't do the addslashes. But from we see here it's impossible to help you. Where do you get the "expected"???